# Strange kind of Integration (analytical)

Tags: integration

I do not understand how the last step is done. Would anyone kindly explain me this. Equations are in this picture:

[image]

Comment: I guess drawing a picture would not be too bad an idea to help you see how the integral splits up. Btw, what are x(1),x(0)?

Comment: This is from a discrete time process with process noise v.
x(1) = 2x(0) + 1 + v(1), where v(1) has the PDF with uniform distribution between -1 and 1 and x(0) is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. The question is to calculate the PDF of x(1).

Answer (score 0):

If $x_1<0$ then the first inequality is never true, so the integral is $\int 0 dx_0$, which is zero.
If $x_1>4$ then the second inequality is never true, so the integral is again zero.
If $0<x_1<2$, then the first inequality is only true until $x_0=x_1/2$, so the integral is $\int_0^{x_1/2}(1/2) dx_0$, which is $x_1/4$.
I leave to you the case where $2<x_1<4$.